# Vlookup on external workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know how it isn't working.
I have my active workbook. I want to run macros from active sheet.
1. I want to add 2 more columnes with headers . - works
2. I want to open external file, which is base in my vloop. - works
3. I want to use vloop to find my variable from active sheet in external workbook and save result in my active sheet

```
Sub ImpFPQ()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Imp_Row As Integer
    Dim Imp_Col As Integer
    Dim Baza1 As Workbook
    Dim Baza2 As Workbook
    Dim wksheet As Worksheet
    Dim plik As Variant

    Set wksheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'add columns with names

    wksheet.Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    wksheet.Columns("A").Cells(1, 1) = "KOD"
    wksheet.Columns("B").Cells(1, 1) = "LICZNIK"

    'open file

    plik = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Wybierz raport")
    If plik = False Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=plik

    Set Baza1 = ThisWorkbook 'activesheet
    Set Baza2 = Workbooks(plik) 'external workbook

    Set lastel = Baza2.Range("F3", Range("F3").End(xlDown)).Select

    Set lookFor = Baza1.Cells(2, 4)  'aktualny subsyst do znalezienia
    Set srchRange = Baza2.Sheets(1).Range("A3:lastel")

    Range("A2").Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 6, False)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

I have these columns, but rows dont have results. Can someone help me?

Comment: Start by taking out the "on error resume next", putting it in is only hiding your problem.

Comment: Got 'subcript out of range'. And Set Baza2 = Workbooks(plik) is incorrect

Comment: Totally agree with Zerk. Never use On Error Resume Next on a whole code block. 
The reason you get subscript out of range is because variable plik contains the full path to the workbook. Workbooks(index) should either be a number from 1 and up or the workbook name without the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Sub ImpFPQ()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Imp_Row As Integer
    Dim Imp_Col As Integer
    Dim Baza1 As Workbook
    Dim Baza2 As Workbook
    Dim wksheet As Worksheet
    Dim plik As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lookfor As Variant
    Dim srchRange As Range

    Set wksheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'add columns with names

    wksheet.Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    wksheet.Columns("A").Cells(1, 1) = "KOD"
    wksheet.Columns("B").Cells(1, 1) = "LICZNIK"

    'open file

    plik = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Wybierz raport")
    If plik = False Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=plik

    Set Baza1 = ThisWorkbook 'activesheet
    Set Baza2 = Workbooks.Open(plik) 'external workbook

    With Baza2.Sheets(1)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    lookfor = Baza1.Cells(2, 4)  'aktualny subsyst do znalezienia
    Set srchRange = Baza2.Sheets(1).Range("A3:F" & lastRow)

    Range("A2").Value = Application.VLookup(lookfor, srchRange, 6, False)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
If plik = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=plik

Set Baza1 = ThisWorkbook 'activesheet
Set Baza2 = Workbooks(plik) 'external workbook
```

To this:

```
If plik = False Then Exit Sub
Set Baza2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=plik)

Set Baza1 = ThisWorkbook 'activesheet
```

since `plik` is giving you a full filename (including a path) I don't think it can be used as an index for the Workbooks collection

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-object-excel

Comment: After this it shows me problem with that:`Set lastel = Baza2.Range("F3", Range("F3").End(xlDown)).Select'`

'Object doesnt support this property or method'

I wanted to take my last row with data to next steps in code

Comment: I feel like you have so many errors, you need to go back to basics. Remove `.Select` and that error will be fixed... then onto the next one!